# How to connect to a WebSocket on someone else's website using Python?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, websocket

for the past year, I have been involved in parsing and botting various websites. Currently, I'm facing an issue where new data is being transmitted through a WebSocket. While I could use requests, it would be slower compared to others. Therefore, I need to connect using WebSocket. How can I achieve this? The screenshot is attached below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpsXs.png)
I will be grateful for your help

I simply don't understand how to work with someone else's WebSocket without documentation. Can someone please help me?